# How to load the uploaded image in the

Tags: python, django

In my database, the Banner table's url field value is like this:`uploads/images/banner.jpg`.

So, in my template:

```
{% for ban in data.banner %}

    <li><img src="{{ ban.img }}" alt="" ></li>

{% endfor %}
```

The result in browser is like below:

```
<img src="uploads/images/banner.jpg" alt="" draggable="false">
```

So, it did not load the image under my project.

How can I load the relative path images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `static` template tag:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<li><img src="{% static ban.img %}" alt="" ></li>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: oh, do you mean the `uploads` directory should under the `/static` directory?

Comment: Yes, that's how Django will know about your static files

Comment: You can of course change the directory of your static files in settings. But that's not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Where are your `uploads/images/` folders located? If they are in /static/, you could do this in the src attribute: `src="{{ '/static/' + ban.img }}"`